# Another ring homomorphism question

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Define a function $\phi: \mathbb{R}[x] \to \mathbb{C}$ by $\phi(f(x)) = f(i),   \forall f(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x]$.

1. Is $\phi$ a ring homomorphism?
2. Find a concrete $f(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ such that $deg(f(x)) = 3$ and $deg(\phi(f(x))) = 0.$
3. Find a concrete $g(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ such that $(\phi(g(x))) = 13 -45i$.

**My attempt:** I know this is a very elementary level question, but I need to make sure I am doing it right. So, here it goes:

1. I am slightly confused here. Can we just say that $\phi$ is a ring homomorphism because $\phi(f(x)+g(x))=\phi((f+g)(x)) = (f+g)(i) = f(i)+g(i) = \phi(f(x)) + \phi(g(x))$  and $\phi(f(x)g(x))=\phi((fg)(x)) = (fg)(i) = f(i)g(i) = \phi(f(x)\phi(g(x))?$
2. Let, $f(x) = x^3 + x $. Then, $\phi(f(x)) = i^3 + i = -i + i  = 0.$ Is this correct?
3. Let, $g(x) = 13 - 45x$. Then, $\phi(g(x)) = 13 - 45i$

Comment: yes$~~~~~~~~~~~$

Comment: Seems correct, however for 1 check if your def of ring homomorphism requires $f(1)=1$.  It's satisfied but you may need to say it for completeness.

Comment: I guess I could check, but the definition we've learned doesn't require us to check $f(1) = 1$

Comment: @GregoryGrant Since the codomain is a field (domain would suffice) and the map is not constantly $0$, the fact that $\phi(1)=1$ is automatic.

Comment: @egreg it may be automatic but that still needs to be noted in the solution if indeed it's required by the particular definition used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes. Alternatively, you can use the *universal property* of polynomial rings to note that "evaluating at a point" is always a ring homomorphism
2. What is the degree of a complex number, anyway?
3. Yes

Comment: @OP beware that $(1)$ is true only for *commutative* rings (or $R$-algebras). Indeed evaluating $\,rx = xr\,$ at $\,s\in S\,$ yields $\,rs = sr\,$ so $\,r\,$ commutes with all elements of $\,S.\,$ This necessary condition turns out to be sufficient for evaluation maps to be ring homs.